# How to write to a variable using ejs?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I am using an ejs templating engine. An array is stored in system.os. It needs to be written to the osdata variable, so that later it can be used to build the digram on chart.js.

HTML:

```
<%= let osdata = user.name %> // doesn't work
<canvas id="deviceChart" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
```

JS:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('deviceChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green'],
        datasets: [{
            label: ' всего ',
            data: osdata, //osdata
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192)',
            ],  
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by adding a div element then calling it inside the script like this :

HTML:

```
<div id="osData" data-os= <%= user.name %> ></div>
<canvas id="deviceChart" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
```

JS:

```
<script>
let osData = document.getElementById('osData').dataset.os;
console.log(osData) //check your data here
</script>
```

Here you're accessing the value as `element.dataset.keyname` and the keyname is the `os` including the prefix `data-`

Comment: <div id="osData" data-os= " ["Windows10","Windows7","LINUX7","MAC OS13"]"></div> // JSON


let osname = document.getElementById('osName').dataset.osname; //syntaxerror unexpected end of json

Comment: You've written it the wrong way. Write in this way `<div id="osData" data-osname= ' ["Windows10","Windows7","LINUX7","MAC OS13"] '></div>` and call it by `let osname = document.getElementById('osData').dataset.osname;` And also check my code again, earlier I made a slight mistake of writing the ejs

Answer (score 0):

If you need to create a variable that's meant to be accessible to javascript running *client-side in the browser*, you should use EJS to declare it in a `<script>` tag:

```
<script>let osdata = <%= user.name %>;</script>
<canvas id="deviceChart" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: To add to this, you want to make sure to pass the `user` variable in the `data` object of the `ejs.render()` method in the back end